# Generic parameter with reference used as function pointer argument

Tags: rust

I am having trouble figuring out what lifetime parameter will work for this, so my current workarounds include transmutes or raw pointers. I have a structure holding a function pointer with a generic as a parameter:

```
struct CB<Data> {
    cb: fn(Data) -> usize
}
```

I would like to store an instance of that, parameterized by some type containing a reference, in some other structure that implements a trait with one method, and use that trait method to call the function pointer in CB.

```
struct Holder<'a> {
    c: CB<Option<&'a usize>>
}
trait Exec {
    fn exec(&self, v: &usize) -> usize;
}
impl<'a> Holder<'a> {
    fn exec_aux(&self, v: &'a usize) -> usize {
        (self.c.cb)(Some(v))
    }
}
impl<'a> Exec for Holder<'a> {
    fn exec(&self, v: &usize) -> usize
    {
        self.exec_aux(v)
    }
}
```

This gives me a lifetime error for the 'Exec' impl of Holder:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
```

Simply calling `exec_aux` works fine as long as I don't define that `Exec` impl:

```
fn main() {
    let h = Holder { c: CB{cb:cbf}};
    let v = 12;
    println!("{}", h.exec_aux(&v));
}
```

Also, making CB not generic also makes this work:

```
struct CB {
    cb: fn(Option<&usize>) -> usize
}
```

The parameter in my actual code is not a `usize` but something big that I would rather not copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetimes in your `Exec` trait are implicitly this:

```rust
trait Exec {
    fn exec<'s, 'a>(&'s self, v: &'a usize) -> usize;
}
```

In other words, types that implement `Exec` need to accept *any* lifetimes `'s` and `'a`. However, your `Holder::exec_aux` method expects a specific lifetime `'a` that's tied to the lifetime parameter of the `Holder` type.

To make this work, you need to add `'a` as a lifetime parameter to the `Exec` trait instead, so that you can implement the trait specifically for that lifetime:

```rust
trait Exec<'a> {
//        ^^^^         vv
    fn exec(&self, v: &'a usize) -> usize;
}

impl<'a> Exec<'a> for Holder<'a> {
//           ^^^^      vv
    fn exec(&self, v: &'a usize) -> usize
    {
        self.exec_aux(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So would it be considered bad form, say in library/crate, to make these implicit lifetimes explicit for new traits, even if I am not sure they will be implemented for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `Exec` trait is too generic to be used in this way by `Holder`. First, consider the definition:

```
trait Exec {
    fn exec(&self, v: &usize) -> usize;
}
```

This definition will cause the compiler to automatically assign two anonymous lifetimes for `&self` and `&v` in `exec`. It's basically the same as

```
fn exec<'a, 'b>(&'a self, v: &'b usize) -> usize;
```

Note that there is no restriction on who needs to outlive whom, the references just need to be alive for the duration of the method call.

Now consider the definition

```
impl<'a> Holder<'a> {
    fn exec_aux(&self, v: &'a usize) -> usize {
        // ... doesn't matter
    }
}
```

Since we know that `&self` is a `&Holder<'a>` (this is what the `impl` refers to), we need to have at least a `&'a Holder<'a>` here, because `&'_ self` can't have a lifetime shorter than `'a` in `Holder<'a>`. So this is saying that the two parameters have the same lifetime: `&'a self, &'a usize`.

Where it all goes wrong is when you try to combine the two. The trait forces you into the following signature, which (again) has two distinct implicit lifetimes. But the actual `Holder` which you then try to call a method on forces you to have the same lifetimes for `&self` and `&v`.

```
fn exec(&self, v: &usize) -> usize {
    // Holder<'a> needs `v` to be `'a` when calling exec_aux
    // But the trait doesn't say so.
    self.exec_aux(v)
}
```

One solution is to redefine the trait as

```
trait Exec<'a> {
    fn exec(&'a self, v: &'a usize) -> usize;
}
```

and then implement it as

```
impl<'a> Exec<'a> for Holder<'a> {
    fn exec(&'a self, v: &'a usize) -> usize {
        self.exec_aux(v)
    }
}
```